# Linking One View To Another Via A Button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I'm a bit new to programming for iOS, and I'm having some trouble linking one view to another via a button. I'm just creating a simple little app that does some calculations on a NSDate in an attempt to learn XCode and iOS programming.

I've already searched this quite a bit, and I've tried to learn from other examples but I'm having trouble getting the view to present, nothing happens when I press my button (which I've already checked to be linked to the button).

I've been having trouble understanding view programming, so please bear with me.

Here's my code for my button:

```
-(IBAction)resultsPressed
{
    TimeResults *timeResults;
    timeResults = [[TimeResults alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimeResults" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:timeResults animated:YES];
    [timeResults release];
}
```

TimeResults.xib is using a Navigation Controller if it matters, while my root view is simply a view. My thinking behind this was so that I could get the "back" button (though I'm not sure if this is the correct way tot do this, since they are not a part of the same hierarchy). Any suggestions on how this should be done would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing seems wrong with the code you posted, but you should have the Navigation Controller associated with the first nib, as the back button will display by default when a new view is pushed onto the stack.

Also, make sure that the `Navigation Controller` is set up properly in your `AppDelegate`. The proper way to do this can be seen if you start a **new project** and select **"Navigation-based Application"**. If you use the **new project** as a sample to show you how to set up your old project correctly, you will have to make sure that the `nib` is set up correctly too. I would suggest using the **new project**, hooking it up as a `UIViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`, and then moving your code from your old project to this new one.

Finally, make sure that you always import the `.h` file of the `UIViewController` you are going to push to. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. I had it set up incorrectly as a "View Based Application". Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To load another view, try

```
AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
TimeResults *timeResults = [[TimeResults alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimeResults" bundle:nil];
[delegate.window setRootViewController:timeResults];
```

Hope it works. :)

Comment: This would indeed help me load a new view, but I think I had set the whole thing up incorrectly to begin with. Thanks for this though!